# How do I store a JWT secret in an environment variable and then use it in another file?

Tags: node.js, jwt, environment-variables

I am trying to implement the JWT_SECRET I have stored in a .env file into an auth.js file.

```
The .env File:
```

`JWT_SECRET="secretsecret"`

The auth.js File:

````
require('dotenv').config();

const secret = JWT_SECRET;
const expiration = '2h';

module.exports = {
  signToken: function({ username, email, _id }) {
    const payload = { username, email, _id };

    return jwt.sign({ data: payload }, secret, { expiresIn: expiration });
  }
};```
````

Comment: once you have an `.env` file imported, you can access the values via `process.env.FOO_BAR`, in your case `process.env.JWT_SECRET`, in any file of that project.

Comment: @derpirscher thank you for the response. For some reason when I console.log(process.env) my JWT_SECRET doesn't show anywhere. I'm guessing once I get it to show in the console then it's value will be accessible. Any idea on why it's not showing up in the console?

Comment: Typical errors with `dotenv` are that the file isn't called `.env` or it's lying in the wrong folder.

Comment: @derpirscher You were right! I had the .env in the root instead of my server folder. It's working now! Thank you!